# Having trouble installing pyWin32 on my windows 10 operating system based computer

Tags: python, module, pywin32, pyhook

[image: I tried installing the package in windows command prompt]

Why will it not install? I thought I followed the correct procedures

Comment: The error message is right there on the screen: `pyHook.whl is not a valid wheel filename.`

Comment: Why are you trying to install from a wheel file anyway?  All of the Windows packages I see on `https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-352/` are .ZIP or .EXE files.

Comment: I am focusing on the second part of  the terminal, not the line of the terminal with pyHook.whl. I went to this site to download my packages(http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and I did not see any executable files. I tried to unzip the python module file with 7zip but no luck

Comment: Are you trying to install Python itself, or a specific python module?

Comment: a specific python module, particularly, pywin32 and pyHook

Answer (score 0):

Just use bounding quotes for the full path of .whl file.

```
pip install "C:\...full path with spaces\pywin32-...-win_amd64 (1).whl"
```

Of course make sure `pip install wheels` was run first.

Alternative way is using easy_install (not necessary to download the installer manually):

```
easy_install.exe https://github.com/jmdaweb/TWBlue_deps_windows/raw/master/x64/pywin32-220.win-amd64-py2.7.exe
```

But the second way may cause problems with py2exe if you have plans to use it. Maybe `pip install pypiwin32` is OK for you (it will install pyWin32 build 219, should work just fine for most cases).

Comment: where to get easy_install.exe from >

Comment: Usually it can be found in C:\Python27\Scripts\ or something like that. It's included into Python distribution. Even for the very basic one from python.org.