# Installing PIP on Windows 10 but getting "No matching distribution found for pip<21.0"

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pip

I am running some scripts that seem to use python 2.7.5 version, which I already have installed on my Windows machine but upon running it, I see the following error message

```
pywin32 has not been installed for python 2.7.5
```

Based on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39706136/14666607), it seems as though I'd need to install `pip`.

Then I went onto install `pip` following the steps for `Python 2 ≤ 2.7.8 and Python 3 ≤ 3.3`
mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12476379/14666607), but upon using this script, I see the following error

```
ERROR: This script does not work on Python 2.7 The minimum supported Python version is 3.6. Please use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py instead
```

Then I used the `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py` script instead and see the following upon running `python get-pip.py`

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/pip/

C:\usr\appdata\local\temp\tmpuwu19m\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:164: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip<21.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip<21.0
```

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution you can use "python -m pip install "

In the long-term I recommend you either reinstall python with pip or try following these steps to install pip only

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-pip-windows